# Zero out pixels that aren't at a particular intensity of a single colour

Tags: image, matlab, opencv, processing

I'm having a little bit of difficulty wrapping my head around the correct terminology to use in phrasing my question, so I'll just take a stab at it and perhaps I can get some help in clarifying it along the way toward a solution.

I want to detect some coloured lights in an image, so I need a way to:

a) determine the colour of pixels

b) determine how "intense" or "bright" they are

c) use the two values above as a threshold or criteria for whether or not to discard a given pixel

I figured brightness alone will probably not be a good way to do this, since there will be non-zero ambient light.

Thanks!

EDIT: So using MATLAB's colour thresholder, I was able to isolate the coloured lights by restricting the hue range in HSV space. Just trying to figure out a way to do this via the command line.

Comment: Just trying to figure out a way to do this via the command line. <-- Could you explain what you mean? Where is the problem porting the solution?

Comment: Not sure how to interpret "Just trying to figure out a way to do this via the command line". Based on one: did you try the 'generate function' options under the export menu?

Answer (score 1):

Well there are two separate steps. 1 is finding out what you want to isolate, and 2 is isolation

1)Seems like you got this figured out. But for the future you can use the "[imtool](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imtool.html)" command. It is nearly the same as imshow, but it allows you to inspect pixel values(RGB, you would convert these to HSV using rgb2hsv), crop images, zoom, measure distances, etc. It can be really helpful.

```
imtool(my_im)
```

will open up the window, pretty simple.

2)Now that you have your values you want to isolate them. The term you are looking for is **MASKING** A misk is typically a binary matrix/vector with 1's (true) corresponding to areas of interest and 0's (false) elsewhere. Matlab calls these "logical" arrays. So lets just say you found your areas of interest were as follows

```
hue=0.2 to 0.3, saturation=don't care, brightness= greater than .5
```

you would create your mask by doing binary comparisons on the pixels. I will split this into three steps just so you can make sense of everything.

```
%% MASKING STEPS
hue_idx = 1; sat_idx =2 ; bright_idx = 3;
hue_mask = ((my_hsv_im(:,:,hue_idx ) > 0.2) & (my_hsv_im(:,:,hue_idx ) < 0.3));
%note we have no saturation mask, because it would be filled with ones
%since we dont care about the saturation values
brightness_mask = (my_hsv_im(:,:,bright_idx ) > 0.5);
total_mask = hue_mask & brightness_mask; 

%% ALL THE REST
%now we mask your image, recall that 1's are ares of interest and 0's are 
%nothing so just multiply your image by your mask
% the mask is a logical array size MxNx1, we need to convert it to the same
%type as our image in order to multiply them
mask_3d(:,:,hue_idx) = total_mask;
mask_3d(:,:,sat_idx) = total_mask;
mask_3d(:,:,bright_idx) = total_mask;
mask_3d = uint8(mask_3d);    %this step is pretty important, if your image 
                             %is a double use double(mask_3d) instead
masked_rgb_im = my_im .* mask_3d;

%does some plotting just for fun
figure(10);
subplot(2,3,1);imshow(my_im);title('original image');
subplot(2,3,2);imshow(hue_mask);title('hue mask');
subplot(2,3,3);imshow(brightness_mask);title('bright mask');
subplot(2,3,4);imshow(total_mask);title('total mask');
subplot(2,3,5:6);imshow(masked_rgb_im );title('masked image');
```